# Determine if Apple ID is set up

Tags: ios

Is there any way to determine if Apple ID is set under iOS device? I mean not get Apple ID but just determine if it is set up under settings.

Comment: you are asking about provisioning profile or something else?

Comment: No, in your iPhone you can go to settings -> iTunes Store & App Store and under this tab you have Apple ID in first row. I want to determine if this Apple ID is set up.